# Creating Custom/Generic Rules

Tags: mysql, database, asterisk, rule

I want to create a Generic Rule in which user can create any rules and it is applicable and we  get the information according to rules from database.
Lets say we have one master tables in which few columns are there e.g

We get the one information from pin-code now if use create any rule via selecting any columns then our mysql rule will work ..

Comment: Can you please provide more details relating to what specifically you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok......
I have a master tables in which some fields are there I have only pin code in ,from that pin code i get the details of the user like city ,are and country this is simple from a select query but the problem is that when i m giving the access to my users then my users creates rule according to there rules all logic will work

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "rules" in MySQL. What interface are your users using? If it is a web page, what language? Please post something concrete on the table structure such as a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and show what the users are actually doing

Comment: See the tooltip for the "rule" tag: `Rule might refer to various things: business rules, JUnit rules, a rule of thumb, rules engines ...` please define what you are referring to

Comment: I am asking for more information on the question. You should be able to provide it here. If not, how do you expect us to answer it?

Comment: Ok....
Requirement is just like that we want to create a dynamic rule creation from web interface now if rule will created by user then all the rules applicable by user should be work on one table i.e master table

Answer (score 0):

You can do dialplan like this:

```
[default]
exten => _.,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4893/fastagi_handler?dst=${EXTEN})
```

And control all dialplan via fastagi.

Or you can do

```
[default]
switch=>realtime
```

after that control dialplan via realtime database.

First variant is less db load usualy.

Or you can do all logic in dialplan, just select something from database:

```
[realtime_get]
exten => _.,1,Set(dialplan_type=${REALTIME_FIELD(mytable,did,${EXTEN},dialplan_type)})
exten => _.,2,Goto(${dialplan_type},${EXTEN},1)
[dialplan-check-pin]
exten => _.,1,Set(recording=${REALTIME_FIELD(mytable,did,${EXTEN},recording)})
exten => _.,2,Read(pin,${recording},3);
exten => _.,3,GotoIF($[ ${LEN(pin)} < 3 ]?hangup)
exten => _.,n,Set(pin_db=${REALTIME_FIELD(mytable,did,${EXTEN},pin)})
exten => _.,n,GotIf($[ ${pin_db} == ${pin}]?ok:bad
exten => _.,n(ok),Playback(thankyou)
exten => _.,n,Hangup
exten => _.,n(bad),Playback(bad-pin)
exten => _.,n(hangup),Hangup
```

Comment: Hey Arheops Thanks for your code but my requirement is slightly different from this code ok I'm telling you what exactly i want

Comment: Guys I have one Query Related To Query Logic Please suggest me

Comment: This answer cover your case. If you not see how, you probably need expert help or more accurate question.